# Transform large XML document without programming

Tags: xml, sax

I have a file (a few GB), contains the data

```
 <doc>
     <a1>11111</a1>
     <b1>22222</b1>
     <c1>33333</c1>
 </doc>
```

I want to transform into another XML

```
 <doc2>
     <f1>11111</f1>
     <f2>33333</f2>
 </doc2>
```

Is it possible to do with custom written program?

Thanks,

Comment: Which is it, "without programming", or "with custom written program"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with XSLT as well but also would throw StAX parser into play as it might give you better performance on large XML file.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a pretty straightforward XSLT, so you'd just need to use whatever normal way of applying XSLT exists in your language. The XSLT would be custom, though there isn't really a positive answer to "can I do this custom requirement without custom implementation?"

Answer (score 1):

Just use XSLT - it's what it's designed for.  W3Schools do a nice [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) on it.

I don't know what you mean by "without programming". Do you want a GUI tool? It would be much easier with XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to use SAX or similar parser. For instance Python with expat that gets distributed with Python:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Author:      nad2000 AT google DOT com
#
#    Saple demonstrating how to trasform:
#
#        <doc>
#            <a1>11111</a1>
#            <b1>22222</b1>
#            <c1>33333</c1>
#        </doc>
#
#    into:
#
#        <doc2>
#            <f1>11111</f1>
#            <f2>33333</f2>
#        </doc2>
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#!/usr/bin/env python

from xml.parsers import expat

class DocParser:
    def __init__(self):
        self._parser = expat.ParserCreate()
        self._parser.StartElementHandler = self.start
        self._parser.EndElementHandler = self.end
        self._parser.CharacterDataHandler = self.data

    def feedFile(self, fileName):
        file= open( fileName, mode='rb')
        self._parser.ParseFile( file)
        file.close()

    def close(self):
        del self._parser # get rid of circular references

    def start(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'doc':
            print ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>')
            print ("<doc2>")

    def end(self, tag):
        if tag == 'a1':
            print ("\t<f1>%s</f1>" % self._data)
        elif tag == 'c1':
            print ("\t<f2>%s</f2>" % self._data)
        elif tag == 'doc':
            print ("</doc2>")

    def data(self, data):
        self._data = data

def main():
    p = DocParser()
    p.feedFile( "sample.xml")
    p.close()
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```